# If account has more than 2 contacts then change email in contact field as default email using batch apex

Tags: apex, batch, batchapexerrorevent

am new of this salesforce here my code is:
Thanks:

```
public class Example1 implements database.Batchable<sObject>{
    //Map<id,contact>IdContactMapBatch =New Map<id,contact>();
    
    Public Database.querylocator start(database.BatchableContext bc,List<contacts>scope){
      //  return database.getQueryLocator(
      List<contact>conList=[select accountid from contact group by accountid having count(id) > 2];
    }
    Public void execute(database.BatchableContext bc){
        List<account>accList =New List<account>();
        for(account acc : accList){
            if(acc.conList.size()>=2){
           // system.debug('Error of phone'+acc.phone);
           // acc.name='Batch Apex';
           // acc.phone='12345678900';
            messaging.SingleEmailMessage email=New messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            email.setToaddresses(new string[]{'smrafi1437@gmail.com'});
            email.setsubject('Your mail changed as smrafi@gmail.com');
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.singleEmailmessage[] {email});            
        }
        }
        Update accList;
    }
    Public void Finish(database.BatchableContext bc){
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple way to do this, as you'd run in to governor limits as soon as you had more than 2,000 accounts that meet this criteria. Your best choice, then, would be to query for all accounts with contacts, then determine which ones match at runtime. Here's a very basic version to get you started:

```
public class Example1 implements Database.Batchable<Account> {
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext ctx) {
        // Start with accounts that definitely have at least 1 contact //
        return Database.getQueryLocator([
            SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact)
        ]);
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext ctx, Account[] scope) {
        // Find accounts with more than 2 contacts (3+)
        Set<Id> accountsWithTwoOrMoreContacts = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
            SELECT AccountId Id FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :scope GROUP BY AccountId HAVING COUNT(Id) > 2
        ]).keySet();
        // Prepare updates for these records //
        Account[] accountsToUpdate = new Account[0];
        for(Account record: scope) {
            if(accountsWithTwoOrMoreContacts.contains(record.Id)) {
                // do any modifications here //
                accountsToUpdate.add(record);
            }
        }
        // DML outside the loop for performance reasons //
        update accountsToUpdate;
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext ctx) {
        
    }
}
```